# The standard vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ generated by $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have a problem for my Algebra class which refers to this structure. Could anyone help me understand what this means, because my interpretation (that this is a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ with a basis $\mathbb{Z}$) seems nonsensical to me.

Thanks

Comment: Don't think of it as having basis $\mathbb{Z}$, think of it as having a basis $\ldots , v_{-2}, v_{-1},v_0, v_1, v_2, \ldots$ indexed by $\mathbb{Z}$.  The vector space in question can be thought of as the set of all functions $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Is this an infinite dimensional vector space then? Because the question requires me to show isomorphism between this space and a space of a particular kind of complex polynomial, and from my understanding, polynomials have finite degree and therefore form a finite dimensional vector space.

Comment: You should explain us the whole question, I think. The vector space of polynomials is infinite-dimensional, because the degree can be arbitrarily large - consider $1,x,x^2,x^3,\cdots $.

Comment: The question says to show that the vector space of complex Laurent polynomials (polynomials of the form $q(t) = \sum_{k = -n}^{m} \lambda_k t^k$ for $n,m \in \mathbb{N}, \lambda_k \in \mathbb{C}$) is isomorphic to the standard vector space $\mathbb{C}_\mathbb{Z} \subseteq \mathbb{C}^\mathbb{Z}$ over $\mathbb{C}$ generated by $\mathbb{Z}$. That's the exact wording of the question. From the fact that $n$ and $m$ are natural numbers, it would seem to me that this space is of dimension $n+m$.

Comment: Just exhibit bases, one for each space, that are in natural one-to-one correspondence.

Comment: @JoshYoung: The thing is, $m$ and $n$ aren't the same for all Laurent polynomials. (If you _did_ fix $m$ and $n$, the set of Laurent polynomials as in your comment _would_ be a finite-dimensional space, of dimension $m + n + 1$.)